# Selection of stats test for non-normal data

Tags: dataset, experiment-design

in the early days of PhD and still a bit useless with stats. Here's my question. So for context, say for example I have an experiment where I take cells from 10 humans in total (e.g. Monocytes) and I either leave them unstimulated (condition A) or incubate with one of 4 different stimuli (condition B-E). Then measure the concentration of a given molecule.

So for this experiment I have 5 sets of data (conditions A-E with an n of 10). I've done normality tests and two data sets are non-normally distributed. So I believe if they were all normal I would do a repeated measures ANOVA. But what is the non-normal stats test that I should use in this case and what post-hoc tests are advisable?

Comment: Sounds like you have a randomized complete block design.  Will you have a pre-treatment measurement of concentration for each group (example: human 3, treatment condition B) and then also measure concentration at the end, or only the end concentration?

Answer (score 2):

There are few things to unpack

data are not supposed to be normal, it's the residuals that are normal. Imagine you have a very strong effect, then you data won't be normal, they would have two modes, one for controlls and one for treatments. This is ok, it's within group data (i.e. residuals or errors of this model) that are supposed to be normally distributed.

Normality tests are generally frowned upon, since high sample sizes will give significant results even to very small deviations from normality and vice versa. Also, anova/t-test are considered to be quite robust to deviations from normality.

Kruskal-Walis tests is a nonparametric alternative to ANOVA, it's similar to ANOVA, but it's performed on ranks. You can also run a permutation test.

I don't know if 2 subjects per condition, if I understood it correctly, is enough data for statistical testing